# Issue with Kivy movement

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I've been trying to work this out for a while now.  Below, is the python/kivy code for the early stages of a kivy app.  The issue lies in player movement.  Kivy is overcompensating the dx and dy movements and it is causing the player movement to constantly shake.  I don't know how to fix this issue.  Any ideas?

Note:
Much of this code is incomplete, but the player movement is mostly done.  The movement issue is happening in the "`Player`" class.

EDIT:  Here is what I tried following the advice of the post below

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.1.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, NumericProperty
import math
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time
import random

PLAYER_SPEED = 10
ENEMY_SPAWN = 3
UPDATE_SPEED = .01
MIN_INITIAL_PLAYER_MINION_DISTANCE = 200

class Player(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    target = ListProperty([])
    speed = NumericProperty(PLAYER_SPEED)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self)
        self.target = [399.0, 399.0]
    def update_target(self, new_target):
        self.target = new_target
    def move(self):
        dx = self.target[0] - self.center[0]
        dy = self.target[1] - self.center[1]
        x_1 = self.pos[0] - self.center[0]
        y_1 = self.pos[1] - self.center[1]
        total = math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy**2)
        self.velocity_x = (dx / total) * self.speed
        self.velocity_y = (dy / total) * self.speed
        if math.sqrt(x_1** 2 + y_1**2) < self.speed:
            self.pos = self.center
        else:
            new_x = self.pos[0] + self.velocity_x
            new_y = self.pos[1] + self.velocity_y
            self.pos = (new_x,new_y)

class Enemy(Player):
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(PLAYER_SPEED)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self)
        self.center = kwargs.get('start_pos',[0,0])
    def move(self):
        self.pos = (self.pos[0], self.pos[1] + self.velocity_y)

def distance(widget1, widget2):
    dist = math.sqrt((widget1.pos[0]-widget2.pos[0])**2 + \
                     (widget1.pos[1]-widget2.pos[1])**2)
    return dist

class Game(Widget):
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    enemies = ListProperty([])
    decoys = ListProperty([])
    def setup(self):
        self.enemies = []
        self.decoys = []
        self.player1.center = self.center
        self.setup_schedules()
    #Don't forget about good code organization!
    def setup_schedules(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, UPDATE_SPEED)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.spawn_enemy, ENEMY_SPAWN)

    def update(self,dt):
        self.player1.move()

    def spawn_enemy(self, dt):
        x = float(random.randint(0, self.width))
        y = float(random.randint(0, self.height))
        enemy = Enemy(start_pos = (x,y))
        while distance(enemy, self.player1)< MIN_INITIAL_PLAYER_MINION_DISTANCE:
            x = float(random.randint(0, self.width))
            y = float(random.randint(0, self.height))
            enemy.pos = (x,y)

        self.enemies.append(enemy)
        self.add_widget(enemy)

    def score(self):
        zero_score = time.time()
        player_score = zero_score + 1


    #on_touch_move vs on_touch_down
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.player1.update_target([touch.x, touch.y])

#Entry Point into app       
class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        game.setup()        
        return game

def main():
    GameApp().run()
main()
```

Comment: Tried to run your code, and I get an error @ 62 line (self.player1.center = self.center): `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'`; when I comment it I have another @ line 70 (self.player1.move()): `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'move`

Answer (score 1):

In your `player` class, and within `move()`, before you update `pos`, you would check if the distance between `pos` and `center` is smaller than `speed`. if it is, then simply set `pos` to be equal to `center`. If it is not, then increment `pos` as you already do.

Comment: Hi, could you show me your implementation of this?  I gave it a shot but I think I did something wrong.  I'll post my attempt above.

Comment: You wrote `if x_1 and y_1 < speed:`. I assume that you wanted to test if both `x_1` and `y_1` were under `speed`, but that is not how python works unfortunately. furthermore, testing if each variable is under `speed` would not work anyways, because you actually need to calculate the hypotenuse before you do anything. Doing `if math.sqrt(x_1** 2 + y_1**2) < speed:` would work fine.

Comment: I changed it in the way you specified and the if statement always just goes to the else statement, so the shaking is still present.  Do you know what is wrong?  I'll post the edited app above.